# What are the black circles on WD Black edition HDDs?

Tags: hard-drive

I need to know what are those black circles on Western Digital black edition internal hard disks. some WD hard disk have those circle and some others with exactly the same model don't have them. what's the difference between them?

WD hard disk black edition without black circles:

[image]

WD hard disk with the same model, black edition with black circles

[image]

Comment: They probably cover “warranty-relevant” screws.

Comment: @DanielB I heard those are pressure pads. where the robots are supposed to touch the disk while assembling it..not sure though

Comment: @DanielB btw you still haven't explained why some HDDs have it and some don't

Comment: It’s pure speculation, after all. That’s also why it’s not an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are anti-tamper stickers for warranty purposes.

See [this](http://support.wdc.com/Warranty/WDVMISPEC.pdf) PDF provided by Western Digital, specifying what constitutes a tampered drive for warranty purposes, specifically page 7, the image in the bottom right corner.

As for why one drive has them and one doesn't, I'm not sure and I can't see there being any logical reason for it, they're simply stickers/seals over screws. It's possible the second is a newer, updated design.

[image]

Comment: But i still don't know why my HDD don't have those circles. do you recommend to return it back or keep using it?  both of them have the same model number, they're the newest models in WD website.

Comment: @Boo It's just a different design. Keep using it, there's nothing wrong with it. You'll notice the drives that should have these stickers are also countersunk so the sticker is flat. The design in the first image the screws are too close to the edge to countersink. Honestly, don't let it worry you, the drive is fine, the stickers aren't going to impact anything and it won't affect your warranty if they never existed in the first place.